# Using Javascript to Create a XML Document from a HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html, xml, forms

I'm having a lot of difficulty with this project. 
My aim is to write the results of a HTML form to an XML Document using Javascript.I have absolutely no idea how to do it.

Reason why I'm coming here is that I want to be sure that I'm on the right track. So far, I'm writing only one line "\n" just to test things out.

Here is my current JavaScript

```
var xhr = false;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

function StoreRegXml()
{
xhr.open("GET", "php.php?" + Number(new Date), true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = getData;
xhr.send(null);
}

function getData()
{   
if ((xhr.readyState == 4) && (xhr.status == 200))
{
    var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var filename = "customer.xml";
    var file = fso.CreateTextFile(filename, true);
    file.WriteLine('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n');
    file.Close();
}
}
```

Am I on the right track?

Edit: I'm adding alerts('test1'); to see where the code is going wrong and it stops at

```
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does that PHP script you call with XMLHttpRequest return an XML document? Or do you want to create an XML document with Javascript code? And what do you want to do with the XML document, save it to the local file system? You will need to explain in more detail which environments you target, all that `ActiveXObject` stuff is IE specific. And accessing the local file system from script within an HTML document loaded in a browser window is subject to security restrictions so please explain in more detail whether the HTML with the script comes from a HTTP server or the local file system.

Comment: The PHP Script currently returns nothing, I would prefer to write the XML document with Javascript. The JavaScript/HTML files are stored in www/htdocs/assignment2. The XML is stored in /www/data/.
I think that answers most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the browser to create and populate an XML DOM document you can use the [W3C DOM APIs](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-domimplementation-createdocument) with e.g.

```js
var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, 'root', null);

var foo = xmlDoc.createElement('foo');
foo.textContent = 'bar';

xmlDoc.documentElement.appendChild(foo);

console.log(xmlDoc);
```

This creates an in memory XML DOM document, not an XML file. You can then for instance send the `xmlDoc` with `XMLHttpRequest` to the server.